# NameError: name 'word' is not defined while defining for loop to take values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace words which are abbreviations with full words. For e.g. replace cause with because. However i get an error. Here contraction is my dictionary and I am trying to create a function that will take words from contraction dictionary and replace the keys with the values. For e.g. cause is a key, because is the value etc.

Dictionary

```
contraction = {'cause':'because',
              'aint': 'am not',
              'aren\'t': 'are not'}
```

Defining Function to replace words like cause, arent with full words - because and are not etc.

```
def mapping_replacer(x,dic):
    for words in dic.keys():
        if ' ' + word + ' ' in x:
            x=x.replace(' '+ word +' ' ' '+dic[word]+' ' )
    return x
```

Calling the function. train is a database with a column content. I want to find words like cause, aren't from content column of train and replace them with because, are not etc.

```
train['content']=train['content'].apply(lambda x: mapping_replacer(x, contraction))
```

Error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-4265efab94f1> in <module>
----> 1 train['content']=train['content'].apply(lambda x: mapping_replacer(x, contraction))
<ipython-input-109-f0798b6d0ea8> in mapping_replacer(x, dic)
      5 def mapping_replacer(x,dic):
      6     for words in dic.keys():
----> 7         if ' ' + word + ' ' in x:
      8             x=x.replace(' '+ word +' ' ' '+dic[word]+' ' )
      9     return x

NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

Comment: change `word` to `words` since for loop variable you had mentioned as `words`

Comment: Generally *ain't* can map to all of *am not*, *is not,* and *are not.* You need more context to decide which is correct in each case.

Comment: Consider it as a coding question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use `for word in dic.keys():`, not `words`

Also check the missing `,` in your replace statement:

```
 x=x.replace(' '+ word +' ', ' '+dic[word]+' ' )
```

Comment: Now error is : TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: `<ipython-input-122-4f7429b148ac> in mapping_replacer(x, dic)
      6     for words in dic.keys():
      7         if ' ' + words + ' ' in x:
----> 8             x=x.replace(' '+ words +' ' ' '+dic[words]+' ' )
      9     return x
     10 

TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor what are you trying to replace? this is actual syntax `replace(replace_word, 'replace_by ')`

Comment: I am simply trying to replace words like `cause` with `because`, words like `aren't` with `are not`

Comment: You lack a comma between the arguments to `replace`. How is Python - or we, your readers - supposed to know which string fragments are part of the string to replace and which make up the replacement if you don't separate them? Remember also that two adjacent strings `'a' 'b'` are syntactically equivalent to their concatenation `'ab'` in Python.